# Generating a step input in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need help generating a a specified step input in MATLAB. This is troubling since I feel like I can do this easily algebraically, but translating it into matlab seems to be a pain.

It needs to be a negative step input. Its starts at 200 on the y axis and comes down to 100, and it stays on the x axis for 5 units, and then shoots back up. zit also has an offset of 10 units on the x axis.

Sorry about the seemingly simple question, I'm pretty new to matlab and still getting used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but should get you started. I've used `repmat` to replicate a matrix (simply 200 or 100 in this case) n by m times.

```
y = [repmat(200,1,10) repmat(100,1,5) repmat(200,1,10)];
x = (0:length(y)-1)+10; %add offset to x

%Plot 
stairs(x,y);
ylim([0 250]); %set axis lim
```

Enter `doc repmat` on the command line to find more info on the function.